# Files created on a Samba share cannot be modified by the same user

Tags: samba

Under normal usage of a Windows app, temporary files can be created on a Samba NAS share but once created, the same user cannot delete or modify those files - *unless they wait 'overnight'*.

The temporary files have a name of `~$blah.blah` (with a leading tilde and dollar-sign) and these files contain the user's Windows/Samba ID inside. The app being used is SolidWorks but I've seen forum posts that the `~$` filename designation appears also with Office apps as if a Windows file-locking API automatically creates the ~$ files. These temporary files will also appear on the user's local drive when using the local drive as a work-space but users have no problems with these local files. The problem appears when using the Samba NAS share as a work-space. This problem first appears when attempting to save the file - the app indicates that the files cannot be saved unless renamed.

FileExplorer can see the files but can't delete, rename or modify the offending files even after stopping the Windows app and even after rebooting the client computer. If the user *waits till the next morning*, then they *can* delete them. The only change that I can see that occurred overnight is that smbstatus gives different results - it shows this when the file cannot be deleted:

```
28085        1005       DENY_NONE  0x82        WRONLY     NONE             /OurSambaShare   OurProjectDirectory/~$blah.blah  Wed Jan 20 12:01:44 2016
```

When the file CAN be deleted, smbstatus shows no entry for the offending files.

Over on the Posix/Linux side, a user can modify (move, rename, delete etc) the offending files which implies that this is not a posix permissions or acl problem. Also, the posix/acl permissions didn't change overnight. This user can use Notepad to create, modify and save files in the same share and the posix permissions are the same as the offending files. These posix permissions are: -`rwxrwx--x+ 1 root users`
Also getfacl shows that the user has `rwx` permissions for the files and their directory.

**My questions:**

How can I configure Samba to allow users to modify (or delete) files that they've created?

Why does Samba seem to relinquish these offending files overnight?

**More details:**

Samba version: smbstatus --version says: Version 3.4.3-1.32.1-2591-SUSE-CODE11

Excerpts from smb.conf

```
[global]
        workgroup = OurWorkgroup
        passdb backend = tdbsam
        printing = cups
        printcap name = cups
        printcap cache time = 750
        cups options = raw
        map to guest = Bad User
        logon path = \\%L\profiles\.msprofile
        logon home = \\%L\%U\.9xprofile
        logon drive = P:
        usershare allow guests = Yes
        add machine script = /usr/sbin/useradd  -c Machine -d /var/lib/nobody -s /bin/false %m$
        domain logons = No
        domain master = No
        security = user
        wins support = Yes
        encrypt passwords = YES
        smb passwd file = /etc/samba/smbpasswd
        dos filemode = Yes

[users]
        comment = All users
        path = /home
        read only = No
        inherit acls = Yes
        veto files = /aquota.user/groups/shares/
        nt acl support = yes

[shared]
        comment = OurSambaShare
        inherit acls = Yes
        inherit permissions = Yes
        inherit owner = Yes
        path = /OurShare
        read only = No
        force group = users
        force create mode = 775
        nt acl support = yes
```